# ComboBox SelectedValue wont set when values come from WCF service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'm having a strange issue where the SelectedValue of a combobox is not getting set and always stays at its default first element. I'm using Windows Forms with .Net 4.6.1

The combobox datasource is coming from a WCF service(that returns a list) and I'm wondering if this might be the issue. Here is what I've done so far and I marked the part that does not work.

Whats odd is that I can see that the value is set properly(using the debugger) but the combobox still does not change.

```cs
        private void ReporteTecnicoVerDetalle_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
                cmbTecnico.DataSource = util_service.ListarPersonas(5);
                cmbTecnico.DisplayMember = "Nombre_persona";
                cmbTecnico.ValueMember = "Id_persona";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al poblar las personas: " + ex.Message);
            }

            try {
                cmbProyecto.DataSource = util_service.ListarProyectos();
                cmbProyecto.DisplayMember = "Nom_proyecto";
                cmbProyecto.ValueMember = "Id_proyecto";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al poblar los proyectos: " + ex.Message);
            }

            ReporteTecnicoBE rtecBE = tecSvc.MostrarReporte(idReporte);
            
            // The options get populated properly above, but when I set the Selected value it does not work
            cmbProyecto.SelectedValue = rtecBE.Id_proyecto; // "Id_proyecto" is an int
            cmbTecnico.SelectedValue = rtecBE.Id_tecnico; // "Id_tecnico" as is this
          
            // All other fields work fine
            txtDetalle.Text = rtecBE.Detalles_reporte;
            txtId.Text = rtecBE.Id_proyecto.ToString();
            dtpFecha.Text = rtecBE.Fecha_reporte.ToString();
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `ReporteTecnicoVerDetalle_Load` the Load event of... Btw, always set the `DisplayMember`, then the `ValueMember`, then the `DataSource`. Is this part of the initialization procedure, or these Controls were previously initialized with a different DataSource? Do the ComboBoxes have a Handle at this time? (e.g., they won't in case both are shown in a secondary TabPage of a TabControl or for other reasons - not visible at this time).

Comment: Its the load event of a form, but changing the order of things seems to have fixed the issue, thanks!